# Immersive like feature in JB and ICS

Tags: android, fullscreen, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, android-4.2-jelly-bean, android-fullscreen

I am developing an Application where I need to go completely full screen. In kitkat its very easy by using `Immersive` tag. But since not all devices support kitkat I need to take JB and ICS (atleast) into consideration.

Well although there is a way of hiding navigation bar and status bar in JB and ICS it becomes visible as soon as the user interacts. This certainly does not looks good. It also takes one extra touch.

I did a lot of searching on net and was surprised that there is no way we can achieve it. I was hoping to find some trick or hack but nothing.

I am pretty sure that before kitkat came there were games which used full screen so I guess there should be a way (like Temple Run and Andgry Birds). Can some one please guide me in correct direction.

P.S: I am looking solution for devices which are not rooted.

Thanks :)

Comment: Full screen is possible on earlier versions, immersive mode like on KitKat where the user can easily get their status bar visible however is not possible as this is a KitKat feature.

Comment: @Schoentoon but i am sure they were games which used full screen before kitkat right? like temple run and angry birds. I am really not sure but i guess there were full screen. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: You aren't wrong, full screen yes. Just not immersive mode where you can quickly unhide the status bar ;)

Comment: @Schoentoon ok that works for me, I dont need Immersive feature exactly . Any thing that may look like Immersive will do. Do you know how to achieve it ?

Comment: @Schoentoon any help or links will be very helpful

Answer (score 1):

Use a full screen theme, or set it from code as described here https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/status.html
As I already pointed out in the comments, this will give you full screen. Not the immersive mode as seen on KitKat where the user can easily unhide the status bar. If you're going with the theme approach it's probably best to set a not full screen theme on API19+ (KitKat) and tell it to use Immersive mode from there on.

Comment: Thanks one question though will this hide the navigation bar as well (Home button)?

Comment: @Droider Yes it will.