# HP slate 7 in restricted mode android app screen frozen when using View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION

Tags: android, freeze, touch-event, slate

I am developing an android app for HP Slate 7 on restricted mode(created a new user profile with limited access to resources) . The app need to be full screen hence i used View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION to hide the status and navigation bar, when i run the application the screen looks frozen and doesn't respond to touch(i cannot click buttons on the screen). when i swipe from down to up to see the navigation bar the screen looks like it comes to life and i can press the button. (This is not ideal for my app users as i dont want them to swipe the screen from down to up every time to access the screen as it is bad UX).

**So my question is what would be so different between the restricted modes of HP slate and nexus, that my app works on nexus and doesn't work on HP . Please suggest if there is any way to solve this problem.**

PS1 : i used onTouchEvent method as shown below to capture the touch event anywhere on the screen but the method was not invoked.

PS2: This happens **only** on restricted mode of HP slate 7 and doesn't happen on normal mode of HP slate 7, normal mode of nexus tablet or restricted mode of nexus tablet.

PS3 : I tested on four HP Slate 7 and two nexus tablets

PS4: after the swipe for navigation bar the app starts working hence i delete and create new user profile and install the apk again, if you try creating an app , please dont assume that app works after 1 try, as it goes back to not working mode, after recreating restricted user profile.

Edit :I would like to point out that my HP slate has kitkat and Nexus has lollipop

I found a question related to this topic, in which he was suggested to go fullscreen using "Theme.Holo.NoActionBar.Fullscreen" rather than immersive, if the api is less than or equal to 19(Kitkat)
 [Immersive like feature in JB and ICS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24676868/immersive-like-feature-in-jb-and-ics)

Here is my code

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Button txtContinue;
    Button btnClickMe;
    TextView txtView;
    int n;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_short_form_test);
     txtContinue = (Button) findViewById(R.id.txtContinueTest);
     txtContinue.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent =  new Intent(MainActivity.this, 
              question1Activity.class);
            MainActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
            Log.i("########CLICKED#######","#####OnCreate#######");

         }
      });

     }


     @Override
     protected void onResume() {

        super.onResume();
        View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
        decorView
                .setSystemUiVisibility(
                         View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                         |  View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                         | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                         | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
                       );
       }

     @Override
     public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

           Log.i("########Touched#######","#####TouchEvent########");
           return super.onTouchEvent(event);

     }


   }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! This seems sensible, but what is your actual question?

Comment: Thanks! , I edited and included the question in bold.